# Paypal HTTP client returns void

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

This request:

```
var client = Functions.GetPaypalClient();
using (var request = new HttpRequest("/v1/billing/plans", HttpMethod.Post))
{
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Content = new StringContent(strData);
    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

    var response = Task.Run(() => client.Execute(request)).Result;

    response.StatusCode.ToString().BasicLog();
    var data = response.Result<string>();
    data.BasicLog();
}
```

Succesfully creates the plan in the sandbox, and logs the status code as `Created`, yet logging `data` returns the exception:

```
MESSAGE:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Void' to type 'System.String'.

SOURCE:
PayPalHttp-Dotnet
```

As far as I can tell, I'm making the request properly as per the docs:
https://github.com/paypal/paypalhttp_dotnet

How can I get the returned JSON I'm expecting?

Answer (score 0):

The library in question is bugged, it doesn't return any data.  Writing my own implementation works properly.  Paypal developer libraries are a mess.